# Predict x-values from the line in the plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, intercept

I need some help to find the x-value of the intercept point when the y-value (is = 0) crosses the blue line in the plot. My thought was to create a geom-segment, but with this code did I not find the x-value.

```
qplot(number$x,Mean.T2,data=SF01_05,color=Month,geom = c("point"),facets = .~id) + geom_smooth(method=loess) + ggtitle ("Daily Average Air-temperature (-2cm)") + geom_segment(aes(x = threshold, xend = threshold, y = -Inf,  yend = 0), col=2, linetype = 1) + geom_segment(aes(x = -Inf, xend = threshold, y = 0, yend = 0), col=2, linetype =1) + 
  theme_bw() + xlab("Days") + ylab ("Temperature ( ºC )") + theme(legend.position = "none") + scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(-10, 16, 2), labels = 0 + seq(-10,16,2), limits = c(-10,16)) + scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0,200,50), labels = 0 + seq(0,200,50), limits = c(0,200))
```

[image]

Is it possible to make a red dot with the x-value in a ggplot?? The dateframe is about temperature from different locations. So a y-value = 0 (temperature )will probably have a different x- value from each plot

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`? So we can help you better.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: number$x = day number from 0-200. Mean-T2 is the mean temperature at each plot